# Sonatype Nexus : IVY versus Maven

Tags: maven, ivy, nexus, sonatype

I work with projects where dependency management is resolved with [Apache IVY](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/).  I also have to publish this projects/artifacts in **Sonatype Nexus**

I have found that internally to publish in Nexus, IVY file format is converted to Maven POM, and dependencies are resolved Maven's way.

**My question:**

Can Nexus work directly against IVY files without any Maven conversion?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

I would ask, "Why does it matter?"

Answer (score 1):

Nexus does not support custom repository formats or the Ivy repository format. However it does support the Maven format and many others like NPM, RPM, sites, NuGet or RubyGems. On the other hand Ivy completely supports the Maven repository format.

Unless your organization uses Ivy and its repository format ONLY, it makes little sense to use it since you are automatically locking out other build tools or at least making it harder. I would suggest to stick with the Maven repository format as a well supported format across all JVM build tools and beyond.

Documentation on how to use Ivy is e.g. available in [the Nexus book](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/ant-ivy.html) and the [Nexus book example](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-book-examples)s as well as t[he Nexus staging free video training course.](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/members-only/video-gallery-2/free-training/)